# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Throttle Mediator not blocking api request if it reaches maxcount

Tags: wso2, throttling, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to implement [throttle mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Throttle+Mediator+) in WSO2 EI 6.6.0 to allow certain IP. Even though added `throttle:MaximumCount` as 5, it is continuously allow me to hit that api when hit count reached more than what i set up within certain duration defined in `throttle:UnitTime`

API Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/throttleapi" name="ThrottleAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="welcomelog" level="custom">
                <property name="ThrottleAPI" value="is called*******"/>
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$axis2:REMOTE_ADDR" name="****REMOTE_ADDR" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                <property expression="$axis2:REMOTE_HOST" name="****REMOTE_HOST" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            </log>
            <throttle id="myThrottle" onAccept="acceptSequence" onReject="rejectSequence">
                <policy>
                    <wsp:Policy wsu:id="WSO2MediatorThrottlingPolicy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <throttle:MediatorThrottleAssertion xmlns:throttle="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/throttle">
                            <throttle:MaximumConcurrentAccess>0</throttle:MaximumConcurrentAccess>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <throttle:ID throttle:type="IP">192.168.x.x - 192.168.x.x</throttle:ID>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <throttle:Control>
                                        <wsp:Policy>
                                            <throttle:MaximumCount>5</throttle:MaximumCount>
                                            <throttle:UnitTime>60000</throttle:UnitTime>
                                            <throttle:ProhibitTimePeriod>6000</throttle:ProhibitTimePeriod>
                                        </wsp:Policy>
                                    </throttle:Control>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </throttle:MediatorThrottleAssertion>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </policy>
            </throttle>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

acceptSequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="acceptSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="acceptSequencelog" level="custom">
        <property name="acceptSequence" value="is called*******"/>
    </log>
    <log level="custom">
                  <property name="text" value="**Access Granted**"/>
               </log>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <status>OK</status>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <respond/>
</sequence>
```

rejectSequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="rejectSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="acceptSequencelog" level="custom">
        <property name="rejectSequence" value="is called*******"/>
    </log>
    <log level="custom">
                  <property name="text" value="**Access Denied**"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC"
                         value="401"
                         scope="axis2"
                         type="STRING"
                         description="HTTP_SC_401"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE"
                         value="true"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"
                         description="RESPONSE"/>
               <respond/>
</sequence>
```

Can anyone please let me know why that `throttle:MaximumCount` functionality is not working? why it is always allowing me to access/hit that api?

another query:

I deployed the same API in docker container, noticed that `$axis2:REMOTE_ADDR` log returns some IP series like `10.42.x.x` which is not included in `throttle:ID` IP Range. still application allows other IP to access service rather than specified IP in throttle mediator

Kindly clarify on this too.

PS: I believe that when hit exceed the `MaximumCount` `rejectSequence` will be executed

Ref:

[referred this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196048/wso2-throttle-mediator-implementation-for-the-policy-not-blocking-the-requests)

Comment: is this a clustered environment

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna
Thanks for your response, No server is running on my local in windows 10 OS, It is standalone, not cluster set up

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna

I have updated question (see: "another query" section above). other IPs also can able to access service, kindly clarify on this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the same service with EI 6.5.0 and it seems to be working without any issue. In the EI 6.6.0 fresh pack there is a bug in IP based throttling which results in the throttle mediator not working. But it is fixed with the latest updates. Therefore if you are using EI 6.6.0, take the latest updates [1] to resolve the issue.

[1]-https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/update-commands/

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna,

I tried to deploy the same API in WSO2 EI 6.5.0. it is still allowing api hit more than MaximumCount Specified . Can you please check this scenario?

Comment: verified this in a fresh EI 6.5.0 pack. works for me without any issue. Can you check if you are adding the correct IP address range

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna,

after wso2 ei server starts, we'll get carbon url ( like  "https://192.168.x.x:9443/carbon/") , this ip i placed inside "throttle:ID" param, so i believe ip is correct. let me know if your thoughts.

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna
 My doubt here is that even thought if i put wrong ip, it should not allow to access service right? whatever ip range i have given, that ip only can able to access service, that's why we're using throttle mediator. that invalid ip blocking request is not happening, that's what my concern

Comment: When you add a IP range, throttling policy will be applied only to that range. It does not block clients from other IPs.

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna

Thanks for your clarification, As you suggested i tried with EI 6.5.0, given only one ip instead of range and noticed 6th request onwards it is blocking in wso2 EI 6.5.0. Thank you so much